# How to convert JSON output to c# objects and store them into an array

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize JSON output into .net objects but get getting the output as null.

I have written this code to fetch JSON data and deserialize it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public enum httpverb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string item_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string item_name { get; set; }
        public string hsn_or_sac { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public string image_name { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }       
        public string cf_category { get; set; }
        public string cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_time { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_modified_time { get; set; }
        public bool track_serial_number { get; set; }
    }
    class APIs
    {
         xxxxxcode goes here to fetch JSON from API and store into variable strResponseValue
         string Jsoncontent = strResponseValue;   //Jsoncontent holds json data
         Item books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(Jsoncontent);
         //how to access each object.
}
}
```

This is the JSON output which has to be deserialized.

```
  {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "items": [
        {
            "item_id": "519558000025988777",
            "name": "0",
            "image_document_id": "",
            "item_name": "0",
            "hsn_or_sac": "",
            "sku": "",
            "image_name": "",
            "status": "active",
            "source": "user",
            "is_linked_with_zohocrm": false,
            "zcrm_product_id": "",
            "description": "",
            "item_tax_preferences": [
                {
                    "tax_specification": "inter",
                    "tax_type": 0,
                    "tax_name": "IGST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076071"
                },
                {
                    "tax_specification": "intra",
                    "tax_type": 2,
                    "tax_name": "GST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076077"
                }
            ],
            "rate": 1439.84,
            "tax_id": "",
            "reorder_level": "",
            "tax_name": "",
            "tax_percentage": 0,
            "purchase_account_id": "",
            "purchase_account_name": "",
            "account_name": "Sales",
            "unit": "",
            "purchase_description": "",
            "purchase_rate": 0,
            "item_type": "sales",
            "product_type": "goods",
            "is_taxable": true,
            "tax_exemption_id": "",
            "tax_exemption_code": "",
            "has_attachment": false,
            "is_combo_product": false,
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T17:31:13+0530",
            "last_modified_time": "2019-04-25T17:31:13+0530",
            "track_serial_number": false
        },
        {
            "item_id": "519558000005300339",
            "name": "Acer HA270 27\" Full HD IPS White Color Ultra Slim Monitor",
            "image_document_id": "",
            "item_name": "Acer HA270 27\" Full HD IPS White Color Ultra Slim Monitor",
            "hsn_or_sac": "8528",
            "sku": "HA270",
            "image_name": "",
            "status": "active",
            "source": "user",
            "is_linked_with_zohocrm": false,
            "zcrm_product_id": "",
            "description": "",
            "item_tax_preferences": [
                {
                    "tax_specification": "inter",
                    "tax_type": 0,
                    "tax_name": "IGST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076071"
                },
                {
                    "tax_specification": "intra",
                    "tax_type": 2,
                    "tax_name": "GST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076077"
                }
            ],
            "rate": 16999,
            "tax_id": "",
            "reorder_level": "",
            "tax_name": "",
            "tax_percentage": 0,
            "purchase_account_id": "519558000000043003",
            "purchase_account_name": "Cost of Goods Sold",
            "account_name": "Sales",
            "unit": "Unit",
            "purchase_description": "",
            "purchase_rate": 11300,
            "item_type": "inventory",
            "product_type": "goods",
            "is_taxable": true,
            "tax_exemption_id": "",
            "tax_exemption_code": "",
            "stock_on_hand": -1,
            "has_attachment": false,
            "is_combo_product": false,
            "cf_category": "Monitor",
            "cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp": "18500",
            "created_time": "2019-02-13T18:08:37+0530",
            "last_modified_time": "2019-04-28T16:16:11+0530",
            "track_serial_number": false
        },
        {
            "item_id": "519558000001595908",
            "name": "Acer KA240H bd 24-inch Full HD (1920 x 1080) Display (VGA, DVI Ports)",
            "image_document_id": "",
            "item_name": "Acer KA240H bd 24-inch Full HD (1920 x 1080) Display (VGA, DVI Ports)",
            "hsn_or_sac": "8528",
            "sku": "KA240H",
            "image_name": "",
            "status": "active",
            "source": "user",
            "is_linked_with_zohocrm": false,
            "zcrm_product_id": "",
            "description": "",
            "item_tax_preferences": [
                {
                    "tax_specification": "inter",
                    "tax_type": 0,
                    "tax_name": "IGST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076071"
                },
                {
                    "tax_specification": "intra",
                    "tax_type": 2,
                    "tax_name": "GST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076077"
                }
            ],
            "rate": 9000,
            "tax_id": "",
            "reorder_level": "",
            "tax_name": "",
            "tax_percentage": 0,
            "purchase_account_id": "519558000000043003",
            "purchase_account_name": "Cost of Goods Sold",
            "account_name": "Sales",
            "unit": "Unit",
            "purchase_description": "",
            "purchase_rate": 6600,
            "item_type": "inventory",
            "product_type": "goods",
            "is_taxable": true,
            "tax_exemption_id": "",
            "tax_exemption_code": "",
            "stock_on_hand": 2,
            "has_attachment": false,
            "is_combo_product": false,
            "cf_category": "Monitor",
            "cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp": "0",
            "created_time": "2018-08-31T12:53:35+0530",
            "last_modified_time": "2018-12-13T21:01:59+0530",
            "track_serial_number": false
        },
        {
            "item_id": "519558000005612779",
            "name": "ADATA XPG GAMMIX D10 8GB DDR4 RAM 2666MHz for Desktop RAM",
            "image_document_id": "",
            "item_name": "ADATA XPG GAMMIX D10 8GB DDR4 RAM 2666MHz for Desktop RAM",
            "hsn_or_sac": "8473",
            "sku": "AX4U266638G16-SRG",
            "image_name": "",
            "status": "active",
            "source": "user",
            "is_linked_with_zohocrm": false,
            "zcrm_product_id": "",
            "description": "",
            "item_tax_preferences": [
                {
                    "tax_specification": "inter",
                    "tax_type": 0,
                    "tax_name": "IGST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076071"
                },
                {
                    "tax_specification": "intra",
                    "tax_type": 2,
                    "tax_name": "GST18",
                    "tax_percentage": 18,
                    "tax_id": "519558000000076077"
                }
            ],
            "rate": 4999,
            "tax_id": "",
            "reorder_level": "",
            "tax_name": "",
            "tax_percentage": 0,
            "purchase_account_id": "519558000000043003",
            "purchase_account_name": "Cost of Goods Sold",
            "account_name": "Sales",
            "unit": "Unit",
            "purchase_description": "",
            "purchase_rate": 3100,
            "item_type": "inventory",
            "product_type": "goods",
            "is_taxable": true,
            "tax_exemption_id": "",
            "tax_exemption_code": "",
            "stock_on_hand": 2,
            "has_attachment": false,
            "is_combo_product": false,
            "cf_category": "RAM",
            "cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp": "14999",
            "created_time": "2019-03-01T18:06:05+0530",
            "last_modified_time": "2019-04-27T17:08:53+0530",
            "track_serial_number": false
        }
    ],
    "page_context": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 200,
        "has_more_page": true,
        "report_name": "Items",
        "applied_filter": "Status.All",
        "custom_fields": [],
        "sort_column": "name",
        "sort_order": "A"
    }
}
```

The output of the provided JSON must be deserialized into C# objects and stored into the array.

Comment: Copy & paste your JSON text on https://app.quicktype.io and it would create the C# code for you.

Comment: Here is your C# code: https://app.quicktype.io?share=RYdg5eAoI2JbmNfokPeK

Comment: Brother this is very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not de-serializing because you didn't add a root-level object correctly.

I modeled your JSON response and made POCO(s) to model it with proper pascal cased public properties as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page_context")]
    public PageContext PageContext { get; set; }
}

public class PageContext
{
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("per_page")]
    public int PerPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("has_more_page")]
    public bool HasMorePage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("report_name")]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("applied_filter")]
    public string AppliedFilter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_fields")]
    public object[] CustomFields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sort_column")]
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sort_order")]
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("item_id")]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image_document_id")]
    public string ImageDocumentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hsn_or_sac")]
    public string HsnOrSac { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sku")]
    public string SKU { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image_name")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_linked_with_zohocrm")]
    public bool IsLinkedWithZohocrm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("zcrm_product_id")]
    public string ZcrmProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_tax_preferences")]
    public ItemTaxPreference[] ItemTaxPreferences { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rate")]
    public float Rate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_id")]
    public string TaxId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reorder_level")]
    public string ReorderLevel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_name")]
    public string TaxName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_percentage")]
    public int TaxPercentage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("purchase_account_id")]
    public string PurchaseAccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("purchase_account_name")]
    public string PurchaseAccountName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("account_name")]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("purchase_description")]
    public string PurchaseDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("purchase_rate")]
    public int PurchaseRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_type")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_type")]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_taxable")]
    public bool IsTaxable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_exemption_id")]
    public string TaxExemptionId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_exemption_code")]
    public string TaxExemptionCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("has_attachment")]
    public bool HasAttachment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_combo_product")]
    public bool IsComboProduct { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_time")]
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_modified_time")]
    public DateTime LastModifiedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("track_serial_number")]
    public bool TrackSerialNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock_on_hand")]
    public int StockOnHand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cf_category")]
    public string CfCategory { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp")]
    public string CfMaximumRetailPriceMRP { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTaxPreference
{
    [JsonProperty("tax_specification")]
    public string TaxSpecification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_type")]
    public int tax_type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_name")]
    public string TaxName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_percentage")]
    public int TaxPercentage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_id")]
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
}
```

---

Here's a sample code to de-serialize it correctly.

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = @"
        {
                'code': 0,
                'message': 'success',
                'items': [
                    {
                        'item_id': '519558000025988777',
                        'name': '0',
                        'image_document_id': '',
                        'item_name': '0',
                        'hsn_or_sac': '',
                        'sku': '',
                        'image_name': '',
                        'status': 'active',
                        'source': 'user',
                        'is_linked_with_zohocrm': false,
                        'zcrm_product_id': '',
                        'description': '',
                        'item_tax_preferences': [
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'inter',
                                'tax_type': 0,
                                'tax_name': 'IGST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076071'
                            },
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'intra',
                                'tax_type': 2,
                                'tax_name': 'GST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076077'
                            }
                        ],
                        'rate': 1439.84,
                        'tax_id': '',
                        'reorder_level': '',
                        'tax_name': '',
                        'tax_percentage': 0,
                        'purchase_account_id': '',
                        'purchase_account_name': '',
                        'account_name': 'Sales',
                        'unit': '',
                        'purchase_description': '',
                        'purchase_rate': 0,
                        'item_type': 'sales',
                        'product_type': 'goods',
                        'is_taxable': true,
                        'tax_exemption_id': '',
                        'tax_exemption_code': '',
                        'has_attachment': false,
                        'is_combo_product': false,
                        'created_time': '2019-04-25T17:31:13+0530',
                        'last_modified_time': '2019-04-25T17:31:13+0530',
                        'track_serial_number': false
                    },
                    {
                        'item_id': '519558000005300339',
                        'name': 'Acer HA270 27\' Full HD IPS White Color Ultra Slim Monitor',
                        'image_document_id': '',
                        'item_name': 'Acer HA270 27\' Full HD IPS White Color Ultra Slim Monitor',
                        'hsn_or_sac': '8528',
                        'sku': 'HA270',
                        'image_name': '',
                        'status': 'active',
                        'source': 'user',
                        'is_linked_with_zohocrm': false,
                        'zcrm_product_id': '',
                        'description': '',
                        'item_tax_preferences': [
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'inter',
                                'tax_type': 0,
                                'tax_name': 'IGST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076071'
                            },
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'intra',
                                'tax_type': 2,
                                'tax_name': 'GST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076077'
                            }
                        ],
                        'rate': 16999,
                        'tax_id': '',
                        'reorder_level': '',
                        'tax_name': '',
                        'tax_percentage': 0,
                        'purchase_account_id': '519558000000043003',
                        'purchase_account_name': 'Cost of Goods Sold',
                        'account_name': 'Sales',
                        'unit': 'Unit',
                        'purchase_description': '',
                        'purchase_rate': 11300,
                        'item_type': 'inventory',
                        'product_type': 'goods',
                        'is_taxable': true,
                        'tax_exemption_id': '',
                        'tax_exemption_code': '',
                        'stock_on_hand': -1,
                        'has_attachment': false,
                        'is_combo_product': false,
                        'cf_category': 'Monitor',
                        'cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp': '18500',
                        'created_time': '2019-02-13T18:08:37+0530',
                        'last_modified_time': '2019-04-28T16:16:11+0530',
                        'track_serial_number': false
                    },
                    {
                        'item_id': '519558000001595908',
                        'name': 'Acer KA240H bd 24-inch Full HD (1920 x 1080) Display (VGA, DVI Ports)',
                        'image_document_id': '',
                        'item_name': 'Acer KA240H bd 24-inch Full HD (1920 x 1080) Display (VGA, DVI Ports)',
                        'hsn_or_sac': '8528',
                        'sku': 'KA240H',
                        'image_name': '',
                        'status': 'active',
                        'source': 'user',
                        'is_linked_with_zohocrm': false,
                        'zcrm_product_id': '',
                        'description': '',
                        'item_tax_preferences': [
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'inter',
                                'tax_type': 0,
                                'tax_name': 'IGST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076071'
                            },
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'intra',
                                'tax_type': 2,
                                'tax_name': 'GST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076077'
                            }
                        ],
                        'rate': 9000,
                        'tax_id': '',
                        'reorder_level': '',
                        'tax_name': '',
                        'tax_percentage': 0,
                        'purchase_account_id': '519558000000043003',
                        'purchase_account_name': 'Cost of Goods Sold',
                        'account_name': 'Sales',
                        'unit': 'Unit',
                        'purchase_description': '',
                        'purchase_rate': 6600,
                        'item_type': 'inventory',
                        'product_type': 'goods',
                        'is_taxable': true,
                        'tax_exemption_id': '',
                        'tax_exemption_code': '',
                        'stock_on_hand': 2,
                        'has_attachment': false,
                        'is_combo_product': false,
                        'cf_category': 'Monitor',
                        'cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp': '0',
                        'created_time': '2018-08-31T12:53:35+0530',
                        'last_modified_time': '2018-12-13T21:01:59+0530',
                        'track_serial_number': false
                    },
                    {
                        'item_id': '519558000005612779',
                        'name': 'ADATA XPG GAMMIX D10 8GB DDR4 RAM 2666MHz for Desktop RAM',
                        'image_document_id': '',
                        'item_name': 'ADATA XPG GAMMIX D10 8GB DDR4 RAM 2666MHz for Desktop RAM',
                        'hsn_or_sac': '8473',
                        'sku': 'AX4U266638G16-SRG',
                        'image_name': '',
                        'status': 'active',
                        'source': 'user',
                        'is_linked_with_zohocrm': false,
                        'zcrm_product_id': '',
                        'description': '',
                        'item_tax_preferences': [
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'inter',
                                'tax_type': 0,
                                'tax_name': 'IGST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076071'
                            },
                            {
                                'tax_specification': 'intra',
                                'tax_type': 2,
                                'tax_name': 'GST18',
                                'tax_percentage': 18,
                                'tax_id': '519558000000076077'
                            }
                        ],
                        'rate': 4999,
                        'tax_id': '',
                        'reorder_level': '',
                        'tax_name': '',
                        'tax_percentage': 0,
                        'purchase_account_id': '519558000000043003',
                        'purchase_account_name': 'Cost of Goods Sold',
                        'account_name': 'Sales',
                        'unit': 'Unit',
                        'purchase_description': '',
                        'purchase_rate': 3100,
                        'item_type': 'inventory',
                        'product_type': 'goods',
                        'is_taxable': true,
                        'tax_exemption_id': '',
                        'tax_exemption_code': '',
                        'stock_on_hand': 2,
                        'has_attachment': false,
                        'is_combo_product': false,
                        'cf_category': 'RAM',
                        'cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp': '14999',
                        'created_time': '2019-03-01T18:06:05+0530',
                        'last_modified_time': '2019-04-27T17:08:53+0530',
                        'track_serial_number': false
                    }
                ],
                'page_context': {
                    'page': 1,
                    'per_page': 200,
                    'has_more_page': true,
                    'report_name': 'Items',
                    'applied_filter': 'Status.All',
                    'custom_fields': [],
                    'sort_column': 'name',
                    'sort_order': 'A'
                }
            }
        ";

        Product product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(data);
        List<Item> items = product.Items;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this root class in your code:

```cs
    public class Root
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Item[] items { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your already existing **Item** class you add or remove the desired properties. For instance, in the input JSON, there are more properties than in your class, if you need more just add them in your Item class. I used the class that you've provided.

Then you do this:

```cs
var inputObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

- you need the following NuGet package: Newtonsoft.Json
- **json** in the above code is string variable holding the whole JSON, provided by you. Please note in you provided json there is a missing "}" at the end.

**inputObj** is an object of type Root class and contains an array of all items.
E.g inputObj.items

[image]

If you need more help comment below.

Cheers

Comment: Brother Thanks for this wonderful solution. but how to store them in an array I am totally new to these concepts.

Comment: @Abdul At this point it may be a good idea to simplify your question when querying google. You want to do 2 things. Json to C# deserializing and then you want these items to end up in an array. 

More specifically you probably want to read over the deserialization process. 

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm 
is a fairly well known guide. I would look in there, and just read up on c# in general.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a RootObject class that has a property for Code, Message, and Items.

You then deserialize to the root object, and access the items array.

Comment: didn't understand brother. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your model will be like this try it

```
public class ItemTaxPreference
{
    public string tax_specification { get; set; }
    public int tax_type { get; set; }
    public string tax_name { get; set; }
    public int tax_percentage { get; set; }
    public string tax_id { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string image_document_id { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string hsn_or_sac { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string image_name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public bool is_linked_with_zohocrm { get; set; }
    public string zcrm_product_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<ItemTaxPreference> item_tax_preferences { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public string tax_id { get; set; }
    public string reorder_level { get; set; }
    public string tax_name { get; set; }
    public int tax_percentage { get; set; }
    public string purchase_account_id { get; set; }
    public string purchase_account_name { get; set; }
    public string account_name { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public string purchase_description { get; set; }
    public int purchase_rate { get; set; }
    public string item_type { get; set; }
    public string product_type { get; set; }
    public bool is_taxable { get; set; }
    public string tax_exemption_id { get; set; }
    public string tax_exemption_code { get; set; }
    public bool has_attachment { get; set; }
    public bool is_combo_product { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_modified_time { get; set; }
    public bool track_serial_number { get; set; }
    public int? stock_on_hand { get; set; }
    public string cf_category { get; set; }
    public string cf_maximum_retail_price_mrp { get; set; }
}

public class PageContext
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public bool has_more_page { get; set; }
    public string report_name { get; set; }
    public string applied_filter { get; set; }
    public List<object> custom_fields { get; set; }
    public string sort_column { get; set; }
    public string sort_order { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public PageContext page_context { get; set; }
}
```